# VS 2010 hangs on start-up after SQL Server 2008 R2 upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

Just "upgraded" SQL Server Express 2008 to 2008 R2.  Now Visual Studio 2010 does not run; it tries to open the welcome screen and just sits there consuming resources (CPU and RAM), but nothing every happens.  I'm removing R2 and repairing VS 2010 install (Ultimate version, Windows 7 Professional 32 bit).  Is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem and it had nothing to do with SQL Server 2008 Express R2 or VS 2010 corruption.  This is running in Virtualbox and I had set 3D Acceleration on FORGETTING that doing this KILLS VS 2010.  I don't know why it does, but it does.  Turned it off and everything runs fine.  Just wasted a day uninstalling and reinstalling, all for naught.

Comment: i think VS 2010 GUI is built with WPF - thus using hardware acceleration, that might be the problem , but im no expert.